# Some questions about MSBI

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx, business-intelligence, msbi

I have some questions to ask you:

1. I have my DW and I want at the end to have reports where there are data calculated thus I have to make my cube (table of make and dimensions(size)) except that these calculate there how and where I may make them?
2. Can i have more than one cube?
3. Can i have more than one table of make in the same cube with the same dimensions?
4. We must have a precise number for the dimensions in a cube?
5. If ever we miss about things in the putting place our conception (table make and dimensions) we can go back to correct where that will be too late?

Comment: What tool are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. During the implementation of the cube, i can create calculated measures.
2. Yes, we can build several cube.
3. Yes.
4. It is the type of the analysis wished who fixes the number of dimension.
5. Yes.

I found all a response to all my questions that's why i shared them with you.

But can we use a view as a fact table or we have to use juste a table?

Comment: Any idea about using a view like a fact table ?